# Unable to run Maven project (gephi-app) the same way on NetBeans in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans, gephi

I am currently working on a project that involves utilizing Gephi's backend tools and frontend visualizers. For this, I have cloned Gephi's repository, https://github.com/gephi/gephi.git. The following tutorial walks users through how to clone and modify Gephi's sourcecode so that you may add "circle creation logic" to Gephi's visualizer, https://seinecle.github.io/gephi-tutorials/generated-html/working-from-the-source-en.html. I have found that running the project through NetBeans is a straightforward process, build the dependencies and run.

[image: Screenshot of run option highlighted within the NetBeans IDE over the maven project node]
Unfortunately, such an option doesn't exist in IntelliJ and the maven "Lifecycle" goals that I can run (clean, validate, compile, test, package, verify, install, site, and deploy) build successfully, but does not actually run the project within the environment unlike NetBeans does. I am wondering what I am missing here, or how NetBeans can simply run the maven project node, but such an option doesn't exist in IntelliJ? How do I perhaps edit my run configuration within the IntelliJ IDE so that I can run such an instance?

[image: Screenshot of runnable maven goals within the IntelliJ IDE for gephi-app maven project node]

Comment: This project utilizes [nbm Maven plug-in](https://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/). This plug-in provides goals to run the project. These goals are [visible in IntelliJ IDEA as well](https://i.imgur.com/stPlZTP.png). Not sure which specific goal NetBeans runs, but you can probably see it in the command line output.

Comment: I tried using the nbm Maven plug-in. What I have found is that the instances of the application that is run, is not up-to-date with the modifications I have made to the modules. Looks like the commands being run within NetBeans are nbm:cluster-app and nbm:run-platform which is what I have been testing with.

Comment: You may need to run the `compile` goal first.

Comment: Aha. Yes that should have been the first thing I should have tried. I thought perhaps those other goals would have been doing that by default but appears to not be the case. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA would be the following:

1. Run the `compile` goal
2. Run `nbm:cluster-app`
3. Run `nbm:run-platform`

The last 2 goals are provided by the [nbm Maven plug-in](https://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/).

In IntelliJ IDEA they are visible under the Plugins node of the module in the Maven tool window:

[image: nmb maven plug-in node]

Comment: How would I go about understanding what class (the path of the main class) that is being run when running the `nbm:run-platform` goal within the nbm plugin-in?